# tkinterdndをexe化できない

Tags: python

PDFを編集するコードが完成したのでvenvの仮想環境下でexe化を試みている段階です。
問題となっているのは、exe化して実行すると例外が発生し、tkdndパッケージが見つからないといわれることです。

exe化する前にpip install tkinterdnd2を行っているのでインストールされているはずなのですが...。
解決方法のご教示お願いいたします。

OSはwindows10home
pythonバージョンは3.9.5 64bit
app.pyでimportしたものは

```
import tkinter
from tkinterdnd2 import DND_FILES, TkinterDnD
import tkinter.filedialog
from PIL import ImageTk
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger, PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter
from pdf2image import convert_from_path
import tkinter.messagebox as mb
```

仮想環境のpip listは

```
altgraph
future
pdf2image
pefile
Pillow
pip
pyinstaller
pyinstaller-hooks-contrib
PyPDF2
pywin32-ctypes
setuptools
tkinterdnd2
typing_extensions
```

です。
exeファイル起動時の画面は下図です。
よろしくお願いいたします。
[image: 例外発生]

Comment: この辺の記事で微妙に内容が違うのですが何か参考になるかもしれません。[CSV viewerアプリの作り方(ドラッグアンドドロップ)【Python】](https://juu7g.hatenablog.com/entry/Python/csv/viewer), [Python3 Tkinter ドラッグアンドドロップ機能をexeファイルで使いたい](https://teratail.com/questions/293104), [tkinter でドラッグアンドドロップ!](https://qiita.com/bassan/items/0094379024a3e88d4d23), [PyInstaller + tkdnd/tkinterdnd2 "Unable to load tkdnd library" when launching frozen exe. Works when launched from script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69348567/9014308), [](),

Comment: 教えていただいた記事でEXE化できました！ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

[こちらのサイト](https://qiita.com/bassan/items/0094379024a3e88d4d23)のとおりに実行するとEXE化できました。サイトの方曰く

```
--collect-data tkinterdnd2
```

としないとパッケージされないようです。

Comment: 「pyinstaller xxxx.py --onefile --noconsole --collect-data tkinterdnd2」のように「https://qiita.com/bassan/items/0094379024a3e88d4d23」を見なくてもすむような回答にすると回答の価値が上がると思います。